# Is this drive with no indication of failure in S.M.A.R.T is dying?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure

Here is the S.M.A.R.T report for my external drive:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   196   196   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       5148
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   182   178   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       1875
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3305
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       4575
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1395
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       191
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   189   189   000    Old_age   Always       -       33847
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   115   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       32
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       58
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

I can't find anything indicating that the drive has some kind of a problem.

However, while using it, sometimes when reading, the speed drops under `1 MB/s` and some other times it fails to read some files with `Input/Output Error` (Always on the same files). And most of the other times it works normally with the read speed of `~80 MB`. I never noticed any error while writing to the drive.

I've got a backup of my data. What I'm concern about here is that is it really failing? what might be the reason? it has been on only for `4575` hours with load cycle count of `33847`. No shock, no movement while using it.

That's weird...

---

Update

```
SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      80%     15892         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15871         -
# 3  Vendor (0x50)       Completed without error       00%        62         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        62         -
# 5  Vendor (0x50)       Completed without error       00%        62         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        62         -
# 7  Vendor (0x50)       Completed without error       00%        61         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        61         -
```

Comment: You've only included some of the smartctl output, and left out the most important parts.   Does it list errors?  Have you run a short test?

Comment: @user10489 I've updated the question. It pass the WD short test without any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your drive is dammaged. You have 58 unreadable sectors. Once one of them is read your transfer speed drops down and you get this "input/output error" message.

I personnally replace drives with single-digit pending sectors once I notice it.
If you want to continue using the drive you have to regularly monitor if the count continues to go up. If so, replace the drive.

If you are interested you could test the drive by completely reading it out and checking the pending sector count afterwards. The pending sector count relates only to the sectors the firmware is aware of.
Many other sectors could be unreadable as well.

From a live linux like Gparted, Knoppix run

**sudo ddrescue /dev/sdX /dev/nul mapfile**
(Using the parameter --force might be required to make this command work, I am unsure here)

Replace **X** by the linux drive letter in question. Use **lsblk** to find out.

The command would then read out your drive and copy it to the Null-device (not writing it anywhere).
While this command is running occasionally look at the command prompt if ddrescue shows errors.
Simultaneously the firmware will update the pending sector count when finding additional unreadable sectors.

IF you rerun smartmontools after reading the drive out, an increased pending sector count should reflect additional broken sectors the firmware wasn't aware about.

There is another issue: You have already 33847 load cycles in roughly half a year. You might consider extending the time period after which your drive is parking the heads - some drives are known for their aggressive power-saving settings. Consult with your drive manufacturer if and how to do that.

Please note that if somebody tells you that your drive is fine and in perfect condition because the "normalized values" looks so beautiful - that is a textbook response and does not reflect the reality of broken drives.

Comment: I would think a smart long test would do about the same thing as the dd.