# smartctl + what are the Total uncorrected errors means

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smartctl

we performed some tests with `smartctl` command on our *datanode* physical servers,

and the results are as the following ( example from one disk - `sdd` )
as we can see below - `SMART Health Status: OK`

but under `Total uncorrected errors` , we can see `4` on read line

```
Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors

read:   179459994        2         0  179459994          3     121159.886           4
```

what we should learn from above error? about disk health?  , is it something that point about disk faulty ?

*note - from kernel message we not found any error about sdd disk*

full output from smartctl

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdd
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               SEAGATE
Product:              ST2000NX0433
Revision:             NS02
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Formatted with type 2 protection
LU is fully provisioned
Rotation Rate:        7200 rpm
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000c5009ead9b67
Serial number:        W4605ZJS
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Sun Apr 10 07:43:13 2022 UTC
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Current Drive Temperature:     26 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        60 C

Manufactured in week 06 of year 2017
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  10000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  67
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  300000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  1814
Elements in grown defect list: 0

Vendor (Seagate) cache information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 1875105375
  Blocks received from initiator = 187534699
  Blocks read from cache and sent to initiator = 190120229
  Number of read and write commands whose size <= segment size = 259502723
  Number of read and write commands whose size > segment size = 0

Vendor (Seagate/Hitachi) factory information
  number of hours powered up = 42308.43
  number of minutes until next internal SMART test = 44

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:   179459994        2         0  179459994          3     121159.886           4
write:         0        0         6         6          6     120741.496           0
verify: 2979425514        0         0  2979425514          0      18284.914           0

Non-medium error count:      465

SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background long   Completed                  96      13                 - [-   -    -]
# 2  Background short  Completed                  96       6                 - [-   -    -]

Long (extended) Self Test duration: 20400 seconds [340.0 minutes]
```

Comment: Have you deleted parts of your smartmontools log file? I would have expected to see the single attributes listed.

Comment: In case anyone missed it I would like to point it out explicitly: ___This is an enterprise SAS drive.___ Not a consumer-grade S-ATA drive. It has a different type of SMART, obviously.

Comment: It would be recommended to run a long test [`smartctl -t long /dev/sdd`] _(will take several hours and progress can be checked via `smartctl -a /dev/sdd | grep progress`)_, as when a drive is beginning to fail read/write operations, long tests will often be unable to 100% complete. It's generally recommended to automate the running of short S.M.A.R.T tests once a week and long tests every other week on non-enterprise server drives _([this](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/TrueNAS/storage_status_report.sh) is the script I use for my TrueNAS server for statuses)_.

Answer (score 1):

The most important parameters to look at are the read (and write)
"Total Uncorrected Errors" and "Elements in grown defect list".

Total uncorrected errors specifies the
total number of blocks for which an uncorrected data error has occurred.

If the disk firmware has succeeded in re-assigning the recovered data
from the bad sector to a spare physical sector, then the original
bad sector is unmapped and placed on the grown defect list.

In your case "Total Uncorrected Errors" is 4, while
"Elements in grown defect list" is 0.

This means that four sectors have failed so badly, that the firmware
was unable to remap them and replace them by spare sectors
(most disks have some thousands of such spare sectors).

Although four sectors is not a lot, the disk might be experiencing
some failure. The decision on whether to replace it or not is yours to make.
In case you decide to keep it, ensure that you have backups for all
its data.

In other words, as long as the number of "Total uncorrected errors" stays 4 and "Total errors corrected" stays 0 (which implies "Elements in grown defect list" is 0), the state of the disk is stable and you
can continue to use it. If either of these numbers starts increasing,
this is a big danger sign.
There is no need to check these parameters every day, but do so
from time to time.

Comment: I expect a excuse from you because you were attacking my statements and pretending that only normalized values matter. Now you are writing the exact opposite. What happened?! Please explain.

Comment: Your attacks were located exactly here and now they miraculously disappeared:
https://superuser.com/questions/1715033/is-this-drive-with-no-indication-of-failure-in-s-m-a-r-t-is-dying

Comment: how to know if we need to replace the disk ? , can we say for example if couther is grow and grow then this is the indication that disk must be replaced ?

Comment: @r2d3: You insist on reading SMART variables as simple integers, while they are composed of bit-fields. smartctl knows how to read them, but your interpretations result in thousands of errors, even for healthy drives.

Comment: @KingDavid: I would keep on watching the drive. As long as the number of bad sectors is not increasing, you may keep on using the disk. For all you know, these four errors could have come originally with the disk. But if the number is increasing, it would be a good idea to replace the disk. Be sure to keep reasonable backups.

Comment: @harrymc  , can you please advice in which case need to replace the disk according to Total uncorrected errors

Comment: @KingDavid: Let's phrase it like this: As long as the number of "Total uncorrected errors" stays 4 and "Total errors corrected" stays 0, the state of the disk is stable and you can continue to use it. If either of these numbers starts increasing,  this is a big danger sign.

Comment: King David, you are seeking advice from somebody who has proven that he has no personal experience at all in data recovery. He is giving textbook answers relying on secondary sources like "NTFS.com" and is in no way willing to question himself if his answers might be wrong. In other words, he is not scientific. Furthermore he is critizing me for statements I never made. The answer to your question does not just depend on the smartmontools report but on your complete setup and intended use. Don't lead yourself fool by his 400k point rating. Good luck!

Comment: harrymc, 
I was only referring to some selected smart parameters. Your statement "they are composed of bit-fields." is wrong. Some are, like temperature p.e. This is decoded by smartmontools which shows you three figures instead of the decimal value for all values combined. Other SMART parameters are simply counters. Yes, there are coded parameters. Typically, but not always, they strike your eye because unsual high bits are set resulting in extremely high values.

Comment: I would like to point out that this is not a S-ATA drive. It does not have the same type of SMART you are arguing about.

Comment: @DanielB: I'm not the one arguing and haven't mentioned SMART at all in my answer. One user here has a grudge against me and is taking the occasion to vent it, pity that the moderators choose not to intervene. SAS drives may have very good self-monitoring data, but in any case the poster has smartctl as the tool that can read some of the data.

Answer (score 1):

As for how to interpret pending and reallocated sectors I recently wrote the following post:

[Is this drive with no indication of failure in S.M.A.R.T is dying?](https://superuser.com/questions/1715033/is-this-drive-with-no-indication-of-failure-in-s-m-a-r-t-is-dying)

Please treat the "elements in grown defect list" equivalent to my statements about pending and reallocated sectors.

Comment: so if I summary what you said then , you recommended to trace the counter that maybe will increased? am I correct?

Comment: Trace all changes (visually). Pending and reallocated sectors are part of the attributes that matter. Use smartmontools.